# Run docker-compose up on remote host from Gitlab CI using ssh

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, gitlab, alpine-linux

In my docker-compose.yml I use some .env variables. Just like that:

```
services:
  ms:
    image: 'template:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '${PORT}:${PORT}'
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Docker documentation says, that I have to run `docker-compose up` command from directory when .env and docker-compose.yml files are present together.

I want to use GitLab CI to deploy my service automatically. This is the part of .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

...

run-deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  cache: {}
  before_script:
  # ssh configuration for alpine linux
  script:
    # move docker-compose.yml and .env to the location ~/docker_app/app
    - ssh $USER_NAME@$HOST_ADDRESS 'docker-compose -f '~/docker_app/app/docker-compose.yml' up --no-build -d'
```

The question:
How can I run docker-compose exactly from the location ~/docker_app/app to load .env variables properly?

I tried to use ssh with `-T`, `-tt` and `-t` options, like:

```
ssh -T bob@foo "cd ~/docker_app/app && exec \$SHELL && docker-compose up..."
```

without any success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `… && exec \$SHELL && …` cannot work (see e.g. the official doc on the [exec builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-exec)).

However, it seems your first attempt should be OK, after *fixing the quotes*: could you try the following?

```
- (…)
- ssh $USER_NAME@$HOST_ADDRESS "docker-compose -f ~/docker_app/app/docker-compose.yml up --no-build -d"
```

or equivalently:

```
- (…)
- ssh $USER_NAME@$HOST_ADDRESS "cd ~/docker_app/app/ && docker-compose up --no-build -d"
```

Otherwise, could you paste the error log you obtain?

(Also, you should make sure that the `docker-compose.yml` and `.env` files have been copied to your *remote* server at `$HOST_ADDRESS` in the appropriate folder. − This is obvious, but I wasn't sure you had used `scp` or `rsync` given the related comment in your question "move docker-compose.yml and .env …")

Comment: As it turns out, for GitLab CI, the correct syntax to run docker-compose in other directory than ~/ is:

    ssh $USER_NAME@$HOST_ADDRESS 'cd '~/$REMOTE_DIR_NAME_PREFIX/$REMOTE_DIR_NAME/' >& /dev/null && docker-compose -f 'docker-compose.yml' up --no-build -d'

If you run cd command without >& /dev/null, the Runner will simply freeze and it will be not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across Gitlab Runner's and SSH timeout, this is the only thread that helped me realize and fix the issue. As [stashco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6441494/stashko) commented, for your `cd` command, you must use it like so:

`cd /path/to/docker-compose &> /dev/null`

Without this `&> /dev/null`, the runner stalls out every time. Hope this helps someone searching for Gitlab Runner timeouts, just like I was stumped over here: [How to fix SSH Webpack build timeout on CI/CD (Gitlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729846/how-to-fix-ssh-webpack-build-timeout-on-ci-cd-gitlab).