# How to fix SSH Webpack build timeout on CI/CD (Gitlab)

Tags: reactjs, ssh, deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've created a CI/CD integration with Gitlab and keep stalling out on the final compilation of webpack and assets when running through the CI/CD.

This is for a Linux 16.04 t2.small AWS instance and I'm curious if it is a memory / processor issue, though it seems to compile fine if I SSH into the server and run the cmd directly.

*deploy.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Deploying to $DEPLOY_SERVER"

# Once inside the server, run updateAndRestart.sh
ssh -tt -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ubuntu@$DEPLOY_SERVER 'bash' < ./config/updateAndRestart.sh
```

*updateAndRestart.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Delete the old repo
rm -rf /home/ubuntu/deploy/application/client

# clone the repo fresh
git clone git@gitlab.com:repo/repo.git /home/ubuntu/deploy/application/client

# enter the new repo
cd /home/ubuntu/deploy/application/client

# install npm packages
echo "Running npm install"
npm install

# let resources recover
sleep 10s

echo "Running npm run build"
# build the new package
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env=production
```

I added the sleep method thinking there might be some issue with `npm install` hoarding resources and moving too quickly, though it did not resolve the problem. It gets to this final step just fine, then times out:

```
ubuntu@host:~/deploy/application/client$ node --max_old_spa
<-157:~/deploy/application/client$ node --max_old_spac                         e_size=4096 ./node_module

<ient$ node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules                         /webpack/bin/webpack.js -

<_size=4096 ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --                         env=productionPulling docker image gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-10efa505 ...
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 10m0s seconds
```

Not entirely sure about the gitlab-runner-helper starting again, but this is what happens right when things time out.

Generally when running the build cmd, `node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env=production`, it prompts with more details such as

```
Building in:  production
clean-webpack-plugin: /home/ubuntu/deploy/application/client/public/*.js has been removed.
ℹ ｢atl｣: Using typescript@2.9.2 from typescript
ℹ ｢atl｣: Using tsconfig.json from /home/ubuntu/deploy/application/client/tsconfig.json
ℹ ｢atl｣: Checking started in a separate process...
ℹ ｢atl｣: Time: 1319ms
```

which I never see when running from the SSH deploy. Is there anything I can do besides upgrading my ec2 size? Why would this work directly via SSH just fine, but have issues when doing so from the CI/CD of Gitlab?